# JS to make a div color change

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I've been writing some basic html + css to make a nav bar, I've decided to try and incorporate JS into the nav bar that would say "if 'test' is clicked go to 'test' page and keep the color change on the selected page"
I was thinking about doing a switch or something but I'm not particularly sure how to do it.
http://jsfiddle.net/3jp1d0fe/1/

html

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="column"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk"> Solution Assessment</a></div>
    <div class="column"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk"> Design</a></div>
    <div class="column"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk"> Build</a></div>
    <div class="column"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk"> Deploy</a></div>
    <div class="column"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk"> Test</a></div>
    <div class="column"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk"> Live (BAU)</a></div>

</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
div.container {
    display: table;
    display: table-row;
}

div.column { 
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#c2ad80;    

}

div.column a {
    color:white;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

div.column:hover {
    background-color: #a2884f;
}
```

Comment: Find the updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3jp1d0fe/4/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

1. Create a class with the hover state.
2. Add an event when you click on that to set the class.
3. In each of your page, you need to add the `current` class to the `.column`, to make it stay active when you land on the page.

```js
$(function () {
  $(".column a").click(function () {
    $(".current").removeClass("current");
    $(this).closest(".column").addClass("current");
    return false;
  });
  url = location.pathname.substr(1);
  $('a[href="' + url + '"]').closest(".column").addClass("current");
});
```

```css
div.container {
  display: table;
  display: table-row;
}

div.column { 
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#c2ad80;    

}

div.column a {
  color:white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration:none;
  display:block;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

div.column.current,
div.column:hover {
  background-color: #a2884f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="column"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk"> Solution Assessment</a></div>
  <div class="column"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk"> Design</a></div>
  <div class="column"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk"> Build</a></div>
  <div class="column"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk"> Deploy</a></div>
  <div class="column"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk"> Test</a></div>
  <div class="column"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk"> Live (BAU)</a></div>
</div>
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3jp1d0fe/2/**

Comment: Thank you that's amazing! :D

Comment: Will do :) Is it possible to use jQuery to do this same kind of thing but with the additional effect of like "get the page url if page url is 'Test' give 'Test' background-color: #a2884f;" ?

Comment: I'd just like to see an example of how it'd be, I can say how I'd like it to run and if you would be so kind as to point me in the right direction that'd be awefully kind of you :) so my bision is like "check current url for href IF current url = href set background-color: #a2884f;" if you'd be able to do something like this that'd be epic!

Comment: Omg... Coding that would be really epic @Luke. But will do.

Comment: This is close to what I want, but I think I have relative urls that check the href in a for loop

Comment: @Luke The code is equivalent to for loop. And it is relative URL to the main.

Comment: Yeah I just tested it in dev tools! very cool!! Just one more query, could it be in here "$('a[href="' + url + '"]')" the href instead of equals be contains? is it just like href# or ? :) thank you for the help so far!

Answer (score 0):

you can change another element bg color just get the elment by id or class

```js
function colorDiv() {
    var selection = document.getElementById('bgcolor').value;
    var div = document.getElementById('change');
    div.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
 
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = selection;

    switch (selection) {
        case "1":
            div.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
            break;
        case "2":
            div.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
            break;
        case "3":
            div.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
            break;
        case "4":
            div.style.backgroundColor = 'cian';
            break;
        case "5":
            div.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
            break;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="change" style="height:20px; width:100%; position: absolute; float:bottom; background-color:#000000"></div>
<br>
<select name="bgcolor" id="bgcolor" onchange="colorDiv()">
    <option class="1" value=1>Grey</option>
    <option class="2" value=2>White</option>
    <option class="3" value=3>Blue</option>
    <option class="4" value=4>Cian</option>
    <option class="5" value=5>Green</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<p id="demo"></p>
```